# How to locate the element from the popup as per the HTML provided?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Here is my HTML fragment:

[image: Screenshot]

HTML:

```
<button class="confirm" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(140, 212, 245); box-shadow: rgba(140, 212, 245, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;">OK</button>
```

I am trying to click the OK button via Selenium WebDriver but it is giving me: error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"cssselector","selector":"button[class='confirm']"}
```

Currently I am using this code in Selenium:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='confirm']"));
```

Comment: Make sure your button is not inside some iframe. And also try waiting for the button to be visible.

Comment: share the full HTML of button , and check whether element is inside any iframe or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.sa-confirm-button-container>button.confirm"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='sa-confirm-button-container']/button[@class='confirm' and contains(.,'OK')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: @JaffarLone Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :

```
//button[text()='OK' and @class='confirm']
```

However, make sure this **button** should not present in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.

If that is the case, then you will have to switch the focus of your web driver to the required/particular `iframe/frame/frameset` to interact with this button.

for that you can try this code :

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(arg0)
```

Note that **arg0** can be **frame number** , **frame name** , or **frame as a web element**.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Tried this code ==> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@button[text()='OK'] and @class='confirm']")); still getting error ==> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@button[text()='OK'] and @class='confirm']"}

Comment: Then what happens ? Still no such element exception ? If this is the case then I am pretty sure there is an iframe involved. While inspecting element in dev tool just scroll up and see if there is any iframe available.

Comment: Please share the html which contains this button and parent of this parent , basically I am targeting frame. Update me with the same.

Comment: <div class="sa-button-container">
      <button class="cancel" tabindex="2" style="display: none; box-shadow: none;">Cancel</button>
      <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
        <button class="confirm" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(140, 212, 245); box-shadow: rgba(140, 212, 245, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;">OK</button><div class="la-ball-fall">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: This HTML is available in the Image that you shared earlier with us. Kindly share HTML above `<div class='sa-icon sa-error'>`